# Import from appcelerator

Tags: codenameone

I have to project in appcelerator and I want to import then in codename one.
From what I have understand there is no migration tool for doing this automatically.
So is there some guide that I can follow to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guide specifically for appcelerator as the differences between the tools are too big. We created a migration tool for native Android and it wasn't as popular as we'd hoped so it's unlikely we'll enhance it or add additional tools.

I guess the best place to start would be here: https://help.codenameone.com/en-us/article/where-do-i-start-ewvlq9/